# Importing Lepton Thermal Module video feed into OpenCV on Raspberry pi

Tags: raspicam, opencv

I'd like to import the video feed that I can capture from a thermal imagery camera I got off sparkfun for a college project of mine. But, I can't seem to get the `./raspberrypi_video` into the Video capture part of my openCV project.

The sparkfun page indicated it's possible, but doesn't give any direction on how to do it. Has anyone done this before? Do you know of any relevant links on how to do it?

Relevant links:

- https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13233
- https://github.com/PureEngineering/LeptonModule/tree/master/raspberrypi_video